# PHP - Get a String from String using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have many similar URLs. And i want to get a string from them.

For example the URL is:- http://www.amazon.in/Sinew-Nutrition-Decaffeinated-Unroasted-Management/dp/B01LF7Y0S4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1484716249&sr=8-1&keywords=green+coffee+beans

And I want to get "B01LF7Y0S4" value (without quotes)

We can consider "/dp/"the start point and the very first "/" after "/dp/" the end point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/chirlr/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\/dp\/([^\/]*)\/
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/EUsoqe/6)

Sample Code:

```
$re = '/\/dp\/([^\/]*)\//';
$str = 'http://www.amazon.in/Sinew-Nutrition-Decaffeinated-Unroasted-Management/dp/B01LF7Y0S4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1484716249&sr=8-1&keywords=green+coffee+beans';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: Thank you Maverick_Mrt. That's solved my problem. :)